# How to update array state in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update only one element in an array state but i am not sure of how to do it.

**State**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        markers: [],
    };
}
```

**Setting the state**

```
 setCurrentLocation() {
    var root = this;
    root.setState({
        markers: [
            ...root.state.markers,
            {
                coordinate: {
                    latitude: parseFloat(root.state.currentLat),
                    longitude: parseFloat(root.state.currentLon)
                },
                key: root.state.currentLat,
                image: pinCurrentLocation

            },
        ],
    });
}
```

If i want to change the key in the fourth element of marker, how do i do that?

Thanks

Comment: This question helped me to define array on the state. Thank you @John

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Important point is, we should not mutate the state array directly, always do the changes in new array and then use setState to update the state value.

As suggested by **[Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)**:

> Never mutate this.state directly, Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

Basic flow of updating a state array is:

**1-** First create the copy of state array.

**2-** Find index of the item (if index is available skip this one).

**3-** Update the value of item at that index.

**4-** Use setState to update the state value.

---

Multiple solutions are possible:

**1-** Use [**array.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and check which element you want to update, when you find that element return a new object for that with updated key value otherwise just return the same object. Like this:

```
let newMarkers = markers.map(el => (
      el.name==='name'? {...el, key: value}: el
))
this.setState({ markers });
```

**2-** We can also use [**array.findIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of that particular item, then update the values of that item. Like this:

```
let markers = [...this.state.markers];
let index = markers.findIndex(el => el.name === 'name');
markers[index] = {...markers[index], key: value};
this.setState({ markers });
```

Loop will be not required if we know the index of the item, directly we can write:

```
let markers = [ ...this.state.markers ];
markers[index] = {...markers[index], key: value};
this.setState({ markers });
```

Comment: This is not a good method @MayankShukla, this should be always done based on keys.

Comment: i tried this but I'm having `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cd[i].val = text')` how to solve this? here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197537/how-to-update-the-array-reactnative thank you

Comment: @mori which way u tried, can you show your code, will help you :)

Comment: @MayankShukla i tried this 'markers[index].key = /*new value*/ 'abc';' thank you!

Comment: what is the name of key, here i just referenced key as any key of the object that u want to update. can you show ur array ?

Comment: @MayankShukla here's my post question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197537/how-to-update-the-array-reactnative my array looks like this contactDetails: [{type:' ', val: ' '}], I'm trying to dynamically add values in my val. the item inside my contactDetails is dynamically added.

Comment: What's difference between `markers = [ ...this.state.markers ]` vs `markers = this.state.markers`, i've tried the second way but it seems to assign the reference, not the value so that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm trying the same method but it says **Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.** ... Im working on react native.

Comment: @TomSawyer: The spread operator (first example) creates a shallow copy of the array. The second, as you say, is just a reference to existing array.

Answer (score 4):

Try this using create function

```
onEditComparatorClicked(i) {
   let editableComparatorIndexes = [...this.state.markers];
   editableComparatorIndexes[i] = 1;
   this.setState({editableComparatorIndexes});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

state

```
this.state = {
          barcodeArray:['']
        };
```

update array

```
var barcode_text='hi';
 this.setState({ barcodeArray:[...this.state.barcodeArray,barcode_text] })}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to push value in an array state and set value like this and define state array and push value by map function.

```
 this.state = {
        createJob: [],
        totalAmount:Number=0
    }


 your_API_JSON_Array.map((_) => {
                this.setState({totalAmount:this.state.totalAmount += _.your_API_JSON.price})
                this.state.createJob.push({ id: _._id, price: _.your_API_JSON.price })
                return this.setState({createJob: this.state.createJob})
            })
```