# How to update the array - ReactNative

Tags: arrays, react-native

What I'm trying to achieve is an `Array` like this

```
infos = [{type: 'phone', val: '2222222'}
           {type: 'email', val: 'abc@abc.com'}]
```

Here is the `state`

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  rows: [], //this is used for the add component 
  contactDetails: [{type: '', val: ''}], // where i will add the values 
};
}
```

So I have a two `TextInput`

```
<View>
  <TextInput label='Type'/>
  <TextInput label='Details'/>
</View>
```

This `View` can be dynamically added when a button is clicked and can also be deleted. Here is my code for the add and delete button:

```
addRow(){
 this.state.rows.push(index++)
 this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows })
}

deleteRow(key){
 this.state.rows.splice(key, 1)
 this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows })
}

<TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.addRow.bind(this) } >
   <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',}}>Add</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

 ...

 <TouchableOpacity  onPress={ () => this.deleteRow(i) } >
   <Image source={require('./../img/delete.png')} style={{width:32, height: 32 }} />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

How can I get the value of it correctly and add it to my `Array`? 
Thank you.

---

Update

In my `TextInput` I tried doing this

```
<TextInput 
                    onChangeText={(text)=>{
                      let cd = this.state.contactDetails;
                      cd[i].val = text ;
                      this.setState({cd});

                    }}
                    value={this.state.contactDetails[i]}
                    label='Details' 
                    />
```

but I'm always having an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cd[i].val = text')`

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate state by declaring `this.state.rows.push(index++)`, but you must do it with `concat()` and return the value to new variable. For instance (I actually don't know what *index* represents in your case, but let's give it a try:

```
addRow() {
 const rows = this.state.rows.concat(index++)
 this.setState({rows})
}
```

Here's a working example what I assume you're trying to achieve: https://snack.expo.io/HySVtag6g

Comment: i only use the rows array for the component that shows the type and value.
i have another array which is the contactDetails where i wanted to save the type and value inputted in the text input

Answer (score 0):

In my state, I added an array like this

```
info: {
    type: '',
    val: '',
  }
```

And then I added this to my `addRow`

```
addRow(){
//add new array in contactDetails
var arrayvar = this.state.contactDetails.slice()
arrayvar.push(this.state.info)
this.setState({ contactDetails: arrayvar })

//add new component row
this.state.rows.push(index++);
this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows});
}
```

Where every time the add button is clicked the `Array` named info with empty values will be added to the `contactDetails`  and then I update the values of the added array.