# array manipulation in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have defined an array as below

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       resultingName : []
    };
}
```

After this, I perform all the operation, get the response and then push to a temporary array

```
let tmpArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.names.length; i++) {
          tmpArray.push(response.data.names[i]);
        }
```

Now, the data is present in the tmpArray.

What is the way that I can assign this to my initial **resultingName** array?

These are the ways that don't work

```
this.setState({
    resultingName: this.state.resultingName.concat(tmpArray)        
 });
```

Also,

```
this.setState({ resultingName: [...this.state.resultingName, ...tmpArray] })
```

doesn't work.

What is the best way to assign to the array, since I need the data in other functions of the component.

Also, I want to display the contents of the resultingName array on the console. How do I do that?

Comment: at the time when you have the response, instead of looping you  can directly use `setState` no need of extra calculations
`this.setState({ resultingName: [...this.state.resultingName, ...response.data.names] })`

Comment: you can the same data in another function with state `resultingName`

Comment: @Harish - this doesn't work and gives the error `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`
Also, the array will be null

Comment: here your `this` is not pointing to class. check this and it will run as aspected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
           resultingName : []
        };
    }

    let tmpArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.names.length; i++) {
          tmpArray.push(response.data.names[i]);
      }
    this.setState({resultingName : tmpArray})
```

Comment: This is the solution I have right now. I need to assign tmpArray into resultingName and use that. Thats the solution I'm looking for

Comment: Sorry My laptop shut down

Comment: this causes an issue `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` at the setState. I believe it is because the setState is inside the `.then` part of the axios request

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render every loop in array, use setstate instead of tmparray. But for one render issue setState{(yourarray : tmparray)}

Check it out here

[How to update array state in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42029477/7012488)

Answer (score 0):

Simply push element in `resultingName` copy.

```
let tmpArray = [...this.state.resultingName];
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.names.length; i++) {
     tmpArray.push(response.data.names[i]);
}

this.setState({ resultingName: tmpArray })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use arrow function on onclick function

```
import React from "react"; import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      resultingName: []
    };   }

  handleClick = () => {
    const names = ["joe1", "joe2", "joe3", "joe4", "joe5"];
    let tmpArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      tmpArray.push(names[i]);
    }
    // this.setState({
    //   resultingName: this.state.resultingName.concat(tmpArray)
    // })
    this.setState({
      resultingName: [...this.state.resultingName, ...tmpArray]
    });   };   render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick()}>Click me</button>
        <div>{this.state.resultingName}</div>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );   } }

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root"); ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: By using arrow function component this will be preserved in called function.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
       resultingName : []
    };`enter code here`
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    let tmpArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
          tmpArray.push(`arraypushtest-${i}`);
        }
  this.setState({
    resultingName: this.state.resultingName.concat(tmpArray)        
   }); 
   // another format 
 this.setState({ resultingName: [...this.state.resultingName, ...tmpArray] })
 //another format 
 let tmpArray1 = this.state.resultingName;
  for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
          tmpArray1.push(`arraypushtest-${i}`);
        }
        this.setState({resultingName:tmpArray1}) 
  }

  render() {
  console.log('this',this.state)
    return(
<h1>ArrayPUshElement</h1>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

**The format you told is working fine using the lifecycle function by componentDidMount() method or callback function.
Hope this will work fine:)**