# How to update state of one object in array React Native using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'd like to update a state of one object in array, not updating the state of whole array.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState;

const data = [
{ 
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    activeAccount: 1 
},
{ 
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary",
    activeAccount: 1 
},
{ 
    id: 3,
    name: "Max",
    activeAccount: 1 
}
]
```

For example, John deactivate his account and state of activeAccount should be updated to 0. 
So only one object should be updated (he has no data from other users and cannot update all array) - just example, why i use here `user.id`

```
const index = users.findIndex(obj => obj.id === user.id); // find index of object
users[index].activeAccount = 0
setUsers(users) // Nothing updated
```

I also tried to use [Immutability Helper](http://ttps://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const index = users.findIndex(obj => obj.id === user.id); // find index of object
setUsers({
   users: update(...users, {index: {activeAccount: {$set: 0 }}})
})
```

Could anyone help? Is there a solution?

Comment: Hello I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029551/11891289) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
const index = users.findIndex(obj => obj.id === user.id);
setUsers([...users, users[index].activateAccount = 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem in calling

```
setUsers({
  users: update(...users, {index: {activeAccount: {$set: 0 }}})
})
```

In case you are initialising your state with:

```
const data = [
{ 
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    activeAccount: 1 
},
{ 
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary",
    activeAccount: 1 
},
{ 
    id: 3,
    name: "Max",
    activeAccount: 1 
}
]

const [users, setUsers] = useState(data);
```

then you need to call setUsers without object:

```
setUsers(
  update(...users, {index: {activeAccount: {$set: 0 }}})
)
```